# Read and Validate JWT token per request

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a scenario where there are many separate clients connecting via JWT token.

1. The client (browser) first needs to login (and is given a JWT token)
2. The client then needs to retrieve their account information, they do this by sending a request to the server (which includes the JWT token. The server (which has access to the secret) reads the JWT token (securely) and should send back the user information, how do I do this?

p.s. Each client has a different secret

I can do this on a per app basis

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    },
                    Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider("authCookie")
                });
```

But this method will not work on a per request basis....

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? When you say 'I need to send a request to my server', do you mean your application server needs to pass the JWT token to a separate server? Or are you talking in terms of sending the token from the client to your server?

Comment: Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Is there a reason the session cookie isn't good enough? If you chuck an `Authorize` attribute on your controller method, you can be sure that the user has authenticated properly (in this case with a JWT token). Anyway, you can validate a token using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken`

Comment: Yes the reason is because this is a SSO system, the JWT token is being passed to another completely seperate appplication. Additionally the server which I am connecting to already contains it's own sign on system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a snippet from what we're currently using (connecting to AzureAD).
You'll need to implement `GetSigningCertificates` which returns `IEnumerable<X509SecurityToken>` to validate the JWT is properly signed.

```
internal static ClaimsPrincipal GetClaimPrincipalFromToken(string jwtSecurityHeader)
{
    var jwtSecurityHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var signingCertificates = GetSigningCertificates(ConfigHelper.FederationMetadataDocument);
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidAudience = ConfigHelper.AppIdURI,
        ValidIssuer = ConfigHelper.Issuer,
        LifetimeValidator =
            (before, expires, token, parameters) =>
            {
                //Don't allow not-yet-active tokens
                if (before.HasValue && before.Value > DateTime.Now)
                    return false;

                //If expiration has a date, add 2 days to it
                if (expires.HasValue)
                    return expires.Value.AddDays(2) > DateTime.Now;

                //Otherwise the token is valid
                return true;
            },
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        IssuerSigningTokens = signingCertificates,
    };

    var headerParts = jwtSecurityHeader.Split(' ');
    if (headerParts.Length != 2 || headerParts[0] != "Bearer")
        throw new AuthorizationException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid token type");

    var jwtSecurityToken = headerParts[1];
    SecurityToken jwtToken;
    var claimsPrincipal = jwtSecurityHandler.ValidateToken(jwtSecurityToken, tokenValidationParameters, out jwtToken);

    return claimsPrincipal;
}
```

You'll need to tweak it a bit for your application, but this should get you most of the way there. Note that this code is parsing a `{HeaderType} {Token}` format (for example `Bearer {token}`). If you're simplying parsing the `{Token}`, you need to remove the `.Split(' ')`